# Is there a way to download deb packages and dependencies for Ubuntu on Windows?

Tags: windows

Can there be a way to download deb packages and dependencies for Ubuntu on Windows (an offline installer for Ubuntu on Windows) like [cube server](https://launchpad.net/cube-server) or [keryx](https://launchpad.net/keryx) (which does not function properly) except that it can be done entirely on Windows (not having to install a program on Ubuntu and then going back to Windows)?

Could there be a way to generate a list of URLs to deb packages given a list of programs  and download the deb files for the programs and their dependencies?

Answer (score 3):

**The Short Answer:**

The short answer is **no**, because Ubuntu's package management system (APT) is too complex. There are several things you must know to download the correct package files.

1. What repositories are you using? (e.g. standard Ubuntu repos, 3rd party repos, PPAs)
2. What sections in those repositories are you using? (e.g. main, nonfree, etc.)
3. What version of Ubuntu are you running?
4. What packages are already installed? (This will affect dependency resolution.)

Once you know all of those things, complex algorithms chew through package dependency information to decide which packages to download.

Then once you've installed packages, one or more of the items listed above may change.

**The More Helpful Answer:**

The good news is that sometimes an educated guess is sometimes good enough. In the past, [Keryx](https://launchpad.net/keryx) has shipped with "default projects" based on clean installs of various Ubuntu versions which you could use without having to first create a project on your Ubuntu machine. So suppose you're at a library computer running Windows: you download Keryx, pick your version of Ubuntu, and download your desired packages. Chances are when you get back to your offline Ubuntu computer, those packages will install just fine, and you can update the project (grabbing the information listed above) so your next trip to the library is just as fruitful.

I've just released a new version of Keryx (0.92.5), so maybe that will fix the issues you've had in the past. If not, I'd be happy to help. It does not ship with "default projects" as it has in the past, but I may add them in the near future.

Other projects have attempted to accomplish what you're describing, to various degrees of success. I think Keryx has come the closest. But to return to the short answer, APT was not designed to work offline, so it does take significant effort to manage software on an offline Ubuntu computer, and it can't be done *effectively* using *only* an online Windows computer.

Comment: OP could also install WSL.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto, I'm not sure of the specifics of WSL's APT implementation, but I would imagine it still leaves the issue of keeping WSL's APT info (the above four points) in sync this those of the offline machine.

Comment: Yes but you can generate the list of needed packages with synaptic on the target machine with no Internet, then download the packages on the machine with WSL.

Comment: Also, I am not implying that your answer is wrong. It's pretty good! I was just suggesting a possible alternative. :)